# How to store the address of the variable without pointer

Tags: c, pointers

how can we store the address of the variable without using the pointer?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    double sum;
    double x= &sum;

    printf("\n %lf",x);
}
```

Comment: May I ask why? You are essentially asking how to drive a nail without using the hammer in your hand.

Comment: You could change both `x` to `*x`; at least the sample should compile.

Comment: A very bad idea if an address is 64 bits, when the significance of `double `is only 53 bits.

Comment: @P__J__ but it is of no *use*! It would be better to use `uint64_t` because at least it would hold a meaningful value in its own right.

Comment: maybe `memcpy(&x, &(uint64_t){(uint64_t)&y}, sizeof(x));` :)

Comment: @WeatherVane initial version was wrong of course

Comment: A pointer is just another variable. you store the address in it. just use `%p` in printf to print  its value.

Answer (score 0):

You did it almost right. But you stored it in a `double`, the memory address of a variable can be 4 bytes, or 8 bytes, depending on the implementation. You should always cast to a wider type though. Right now, storing it in a `double` may cause loss of information.

You'll need to use a data type wide enough. You could use an `unsigned long long`, however for cross platform compatibility, I recommend using `uint64_t` from `stdint.h` instead. And also the accompanying `inttypes.h`.

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>
#include<inttypes.h>

int main()
{
    double sum;
    uint64_t x = (uint64_t) &sum;

    printf("%" PRIx64 "\n", x);
}
```

This ensures that you use an unsigned 64 bit (8 byte) variable so you do not lose information.

Also print using the `PRIx64` format specifier for getting output in 64 bit hexadecimal form.

Do note however, this is only good for printing the address, and address only. This really does not serve any practical purpose.

Comment: 1. You need to cast. 2. it does serve a practical purpose.

Comment: @P__J__ Right, added casting and changed `%x` to `%llx`

Comment: Actually used `PRIx64` from `inttypes.h` instead, for cross compatibility

Answer (score 0):

By definition, a pointer is an object that stores the address of another.  How can you store something without using the appropiate storage variable for that kind of data? There are no other objects to store addresses, so what do you suggest?

If you just want to print the address to `stdout`, just do the following:

```
    printf("%p\n", &sum);
```

The format specifier `%p` allows you to pass a pointer, and you can use `&sum` directly to pass the value of the address of `sum`.